# Buffer Stragy and Graphics object works fin in IDE, but not when exported to a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, bufferstrategy

So, I'm working on a tile game for my programming class, and I've made some progress. but when I try and export my game to a runnable jar, it doesn't work yet works in the IDE.

The render method that renders everything.

```
private void render()
{
    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null)
    {
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    // clear screan
    //g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    // draw here
    if (State.getState() != null)
    {
        State.getState().render(g);
    }
    // end drawing
    bs.show();

    g.dispose();

}
```

[image: The game when exported]

[image: The game in IDE]

As you can see it's not working

My code that loads the images:

```
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path)
{
    try
    {
        return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the other image didn't show in the post. Here is the image of what happens in the ide: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0naj6ygvgouoktm/screenshot2.jpg?dl=0

Comment: What happens when you resize the frame after running it from a JAR?

Comment: Does the jar contain all the expected files?

Comment: Did you verify that your images are loading properly in the program?  You might want to edit your question and show the code that loads them.

Comment: I know the images load, as i said it works in the IDE. But i added the image loading code